# How do i know what classes can this model predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, classification

Lets say i got a pretrained model  **model.pt**

how do i know what **classes** can this model predict?

i think it is saved inside the model but how do I extract it?

Im trying to understand what https://github.com/AndreyGuzhov/AudioCLIP does

it has a pretrained **AudioCLIP-Full-Training.pt**

how do I know the labels or classes inside this **AudioCLIP-Full-Training.pt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lauthu already said, the first place to look would be the Notebook:
https://github.com/AndreyGuzhov/AudioCLIP/blob/master/demo/AudioCLIP.ipynb.

The notebook mentions these labels

```py
LABELS = ['cat', 'thunderstorm', 'coughing', 'alarm clock', 'car horn']
```

The notebooks shows examples of only 5 classes. However more are possible, see below.

Another place to look for the classes is in the paper for AudioCLIP.
The paper mentions that AudioCLIP is trained on the AudioSet dataset which has 632 audio classes. See [the entire ontology of labels here](https://research.google.com/audioset/ontology/index.html).
So it could predict easily for these 632 classes that AudioCLIP is trained on.

In addition to these 632 classes, since AudioCLIP is based on [CLIP](https://openai.com/blog/clip/) architecture, it also has zero-shot inference capabilities as noted in the [AudioCLIP paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13043):

> "keeping CLIP's ability to generalize to unseen datasets in a zero-shot fashion".

What it means essentially is you could use any common English concept/word and AudioCLIP should be able to classify sounds even if it was not trained on them. This is possible because AudioCLIP is an extension of CLIP and CLIP model has "seen" a lot of natural English words in its dataset of ~400M (image, caption) pairs.

Comment: So the pretrained model can only predict 5 classes? I added a ‘dog’ to that label and it did recognize a dog audio. That proves it can recognize more that just 5 classes

Comment: Yes you are right, AudioCLIP can recognize more than the 5 classes shown in in the notebook. It is trained on 632 classes ("Dog" is one of them) and in addition to 632 classes it also has zero-shot capabilities. I've updated the answer to include these details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Do you recommend I add all the classes in the Labels? will it lower the prediction score?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at its demo notebook: https://github.com/AndreyGuzhov/AudioCLIP/blob/master/demo/AudioCLIP.ipynb.

As a CLIP model, the labels used in classification is an model inputs.

Comment: So the pretrained model can only predict 5 classes? I added a ‘dog’ to that label and it did recognize a dog audio. That proves it can recognize more that just 5 classes